# Bootstrap grid align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to use Bootstrap' grid for blog posts. I want them to be aligned under each other - but I can't seem to figure out how. I have my col-md placed inside a container, then a row. I have Googled my way around, but there doesn't seem to be a straight answer, or I cant find it.

**How it looks now**
[image: how it is]

**How I want it to look**
[image: how it is]

**The code**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="blogpost">

            <div class="pad">

                <h2>Designed by Apple - Intention</h2>
                <p>Here, simple phrases paired with elegant visuals describe the thoughts and emotions that go into creating each Apple product.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="blogpost">

            <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="pad">

                <h2>Official launch today</h2>
                <p>Duis id sagittis ipsum. Proin gravida libero augue. Vivamus dignissim ipsum blandit magna tempus, porta porta nisi pellentesque. Sed ligula lorem, semper non sem maximus, suscipit tincidunt nisi. Etiam pulvinar quam purus, at fringilla erat ultricies ac. Aenean vitae laoreet ligula.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="blogpost">

            <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="pad">

                <h2>Official launch today</h2>
                <p>Duis id sagittis ipsum. Proin gravida libero augue. Vivamus dignissim ipsum blandit magna tempus, porta porta nisi pellentesque. Sed ligula lorem, semper non sem maximus, suscipit tincidunt nisi. Etiam pulvinar quam purus, at fringilla erat ultricies ac. Aenean vitae laoreet ligula.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="blogpost">

            <div class="pad">

                asdasd

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Check http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I have updated the thread with an image

Comment: then you need to create 3 col layout then u need 2 organize all the div's you which you need to place in same col

Comment: Look at http://nicolajreck.dk/

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want your template does not have to be arranged in rows but only for columns in this way the elements within each column will be in place under each other without space constraint imposed by the line. For do this remove the external

Try a look a this [sample](http://www.bootply.com/N4L2wcJlsV)

Comment: That works, but it doesn't but the fourth col-md-4 under the first on the left, becuase there is float:none. But if I use the float:left, it cuts the columns - see here: http://nicolajreck.dk/

Comment: You have looked at the sample? the class  `.row`  is the cause of the fact that the various sections result in some columns spaced when there are elements less high. For a complete lauout's management you must organize the filling of the space using the columns as shown in the example.